# select query with where condition in oracle 10g giving ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a table in oracle database where a column ONSITE_MANAGER  has data like

```
ONSITE_MANAGER 
--------------
jhon
'bikram'
'hari'singh
"'vijay'kumar"
kumar
```

to select a particular data with matching records i am using following select query

```
SELECT * 
from  (
    Select M.*, Rownum R 
    From IMDB1_FINANCE_ACTUAL M
) 
where  r > 0 
   and r <= 10 
   AND ONSITE_MANAGER=''bikram''
```

this is giving `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

but when I use

`ONSITE_MANAGER='jhon' OR ONSITE_MANAGER='kumar'` it is fetching data without any problem.

some one let me know the query to fetch data which is in single quotes and double quotes and mixed  values as shown in above table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [new quoting method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref336) from ora10g onwards

> You choose a character that is not present in the string, and then do
>   not need to escape other single quotation marks inside the literal

So your query would be

```
SELECT * from  (Select M.*, Rownum R From IMDB1_FINANCE_ACTUAL M) where  r > 0 and r <= 10 AND ONSITE_MANAGER=q'!'bikram'!'
```

Comment: THIS IS ALSO NOT FETCHING ANY DATA IT IS SHOWING NO DATA FOUND.. but not giving any errors..

Comment: can you try SELECT * from <table_name> where ONSITE_MANAGER=q'!'bikram'!' - your original problem I assumed was that single quotes were not getting escaped. The above solution escapes the single quotes. By the query I added you can verify if there is some problem is selecting the right table or some other where conditions not getting satisfied.

Comment: right now its working great .. let me try with some other cases and let you know.... thnak you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have syntax error in the query:
Try following:

```
SELECT * from  (Select M.*, Rownum R From IMDB1_FINANCE_ACTUAL M) where  r > 0 and r <= 10 AND ONSITE_MANAGER='bikram'
```

Comment: thank you, for your query its not showing any error but it is not fetching any data it is simply showing no data found, i think it is searching for data     bikram but it has to search for 'bikram'...

Comment: ok.. code means you want my java application code or table data

Answer (score 0):

In oracle :
You need to escape the single quote character like this below

```
SELECT * from  (Select M.*, Rownum R From IMDB1_FINANCE_ACTUAL M) where  r > 0 and r <= 10 AND ONSITE_MANAGER='''bikram'''
                                                                                                             #############
```